# Using a batch file for find a replace

Tags: batch-file, replace, find

I have the following batch file, (this is an example, the real one if about 20mb) in size -

Code:

```
ECHO Assigning Aircraft Registrations to HEX/MODES codes.
ECHO This may take some time....

pause

copy input.csv backup1.csv
pause
call :FindReplace "342086" "EC-ISY" input.csv
call :FindReplace "0006AB" "I-AMCH" input.csv
call :FindReplace "00412D" "Z-WPF" input.csv
call :FindReplace "00415C" "Z-WPE" input.csv
call :FindReplace "00600A" "C9-AUL" input.csv
```

etc

its taking forever, its been running since 8am........ its now nearly 4pm.
can anyone suggest a faster way of processing this?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could show us the code in the `FindReplace` function.

Comment: If you **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47100886/edit)** to include the `:FindReplace` subroutine from your script and a few example lines from `input.csv` perhaps somebody would be able to assist you.

Comment: The input CSV is literally a list of hex values like 400adc 400976 400666 etc there are in the region of 200,000 codes to check through

Comment: So why won't you show us the FindReplace code?

Comment: The code is listed above. That works through the csv file so I don't quite know what you mean.

Comment: 1700033442,David,Manchester Radar,343086,Boeing,B737-8AS/W,fhdudhshsbevu,Ryanair,Null,Null,Yes

Comment: @DavidCummings, you are not showing us the :FindReplace code in your batch file.  You are calling out to the label.  So not all of your code is listed above.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the appropriate tool, like [JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hbxc2t98(vs.85).aspx) language:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
ECHO Assigning Aircraft Registrations to HEX/MODES codes.
ECHO This may take some time....
copy input.csv backup1.csv
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < input.csv > output.csv
move /Y output.csv input.csv
goto :EOF

@end

// Very simple method to replace *several* different strings in just a single file pass

var fileContents = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll(), repl = new Array();
repl["342086"] = "EC-ISY";
repl["0006AB"] = "I-AMCH";
repl["00412D"] = "Z-WPF";
repl["00415C"] = "Z-WPE";
repl["00600A"] = "C9-AUL";
WScript.Stdout.Write(fileContents.replace(/342086|0006AB|00412D|00415C|00600A/g,
                                  function (A){return repl[A]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

`SED`, `AWK` and `GAWK` would be faster - there are freebie versions available.

Comment: you should also mention dbenhams great [jrepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) tool (native Windows, no *NIX tools neccessary)